# Многопоточность и квантовая суперпозиция

Tags: java, многопоточность

Всем привет! Я java-нуб и сейчас эксперементирую с многопоточностью. Во время одного из экспериментов наткнулся на интересное поведение программы.

Собственно код:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Runnable r = () -> IMF.getFund();

    Thread thread = new Thread(r);
    Thread thread1 = new Thread(r);
    thread.start();

    while (true) {
        //System.out.println("Бесконечность!");
        if (IMF.imf != null) {
            System.out.println("Состояние первого потока - " + thread.getState());
            System.out.println("Состояние второго потока - " + thread1.getState());
            System.out.println(IMF.imf);
            break;
        }
    }
}
static class IMF {
   static String imf;

   static String getFund() {
       imf = Math.random() * 1000 + " Это поток - " + Thread.currentThread().getName();
       return imf;
    }
}
}
```

В цикле я мониторю состояние переменной imf и когда она изменится вывожу сообщения.
При таком исполнении программа попадает в некоторое состояние бесконечности и ничего не выводит в консоль (хотя дебаггером все завершается корректно).

Однако, если в цикл я добавляю наблюдателя (System.out.println("Бесконечность!");), то программа завершается корректно, с выводом всех сообщений.

Объясните пожалуйста почему так происходит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что осуществляется доступ к `imf` из разных потоков. `thread` и `thread1` пишут, а `main` читает. При этом изменения сделанные пишущими потоками, должным образом не публикуются (смотрите, например, раздел 5 в https://habr.com/ru/company/otus/blog/353414/ или https://dev.cheremin.info/2012/05/unsafe-publication.html).

То есть, читающий поток не видит изменений сделанных пищущими, и потому цикл не заканчивается. По сути читающий поток все время работает с локально закешированным значением `imf`. Добавление же `System.out.println`, очевидно, имеет побочный эффект, который приводит к публикации изменений.

Для того, чтобы все работало, как задумано, нужно воспользоваться одним из методов безопасной публикации, проще всего в данном случае объявить `imf` volatile:

```
static volatile String imf;
```